# Newtons Method Type Class Haskell

Tags: haskell

Trying a couple different ways of implementing Newtons Method, but I cant seem to get it working. It's most likely a very simple fix, but I just need someone to point out what I'm doing wrong. Yeah I know my code is ugly, just messing around right now.

In this example, I just try to make an equation for xn+1, which isn't working.

```
function :: (Num a) => a ->  a
function x = 98 - x^98
function' :: (Num a) => a -> a
function' x = (-98)*(x^97)
xi = 1.04
iterations = 20

newtons :: (Integral a) => a -> a

newtons x = x - fromIntegral ( div (function x) (function' x) )
```

When I type 'newtons xi' in ghci I get an error that says "no instance for Integral Double arising from a use of newtons". What type class should I be using to make this work?

Comment: Why would you implement an archetypical calculus, i.e. _real number_ based algorithm with _integer arithmetic_? This is obviously a case for floating-point numbers.

Comment: The problem is that `xi` is a `Double`, but you're passing it in to `newtons`, which expects an `Integral a` type.  `Double` is not an `Integral` type.  Why are you converting to `Integral` anyway?  It has no relevance in the context of Newton's method.

Comment: Forgot I had that there. But when I made my type class for Newtons (Num a) it told me "Could not deduce (Integral a) arising from a use of div from the context of (Num a) bound by the type signature for newtons" So I assumed that div must only work on integers.

Comment: That's because of the type signature of `div`.  You probably need to use `Fractional` rather than `Num`, since then you can use `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Just needed more general types. Didn't see the iteration function which is the core of the algorithm so I tried to adapt it around your existing code:

```
function :: Num a => a -> a
function x = 98 - x^98

function' :: Num a => a -> a
function' x = (-98)*(x^97)

xi :: Double
xi = 1.04

newton :: (Fractional a, Ord a) => (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
newton f f' x
    | (abs (f x)) < epsilon = x
    | otherwise = newton f f' (x - (f x / f' x))
  where
    epsilon = 1e-4

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- Prints out the two extrema
  print $ newton function function' xi    --  1.0478970878235732
  print $ newton function function' (-xi) -- -1.0478970878235732
```

This is a naive implementation, if you need performance and numeric stability then the [ad package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) is best suited for this.